# export object using Export-Csv doesn't work

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export the username and the user's group membership (of specifc groups) to a CSV file using `Export-Csv`. However, I couldn't accomplish this using several approaches.

My current script works fine but the output is shown on the PowerShell console alone:

```bsh
$accounts = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\getUserGroups\users.txt"
foreach ($account in $accounts) {
    "$account member of:"
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $account |
        select Name |
        Where-Object { $_.name -like 'Browsing_Group*' } |
        Sort Name
}
```

I want to export it to a file in an ordered manner:

```
UserName1
group membership

UserName2
group membership

etc...
```

I've tried to add to a variable but probably didn't do that correctly:

```bsh
$ArrList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$accounts = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\getUserGroups\users.txt"

foreach ($account in $accounts) {
    $ArrList.Add($account)
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $account |
              select Name |
              Where-Object {$_.name -like 'Browsing_group*' } |
              Sort Name 
    $ArrList.Add($grops)
}
```

Might be a different approach.

Comment: Do you want it as a csv-table or a file with a list like in your second code block?

Comment: I would like to export the received output to a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build custom objects in order to export the data to a CSV via `Export-Csv`. The 2 main ways of doing that are:

- using [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

  ```
  $accounts |
      Select-Object @{n='Username';e={$_}}, @{n='Groups';e={
          (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ |
              Select-Object -Expand Name |
              Where-Object {$_ -like 'Browsing_group*' } |
              Sort-Object) -join ';'
      }} |
      Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
  ```
- building custom objects directly:

  ```
  $accounts | ForEach-Object {
      $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ |
                Select-Object -Expand Name |
                Where-Object {$_ -like 'Browsing_group*' } |
                Sort-Object
      New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
          'Username' = $_
          'Groups'   = $groups -join ';'
      }
  } | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
  ```

  With PowerShell version 3 or newer you can replace `New-Object` with the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator:

  ```
  [PSCustomObject]@{
      'Username' = $_
      'Groups'   = $groups -join ';'
  }
  ```

Comment: works perfectly! thank you Ansgar Wiechers. Im just trying to understand your code. how come you did not use a foreach loop in the first solution?
also, is this `@{n='Username';e={$_}}` a hash table?